# Copy a random file to another folder

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file to copy a random file from one folder to another folder . but when I run the code below it copies the same file every time . does anyone know what's wrong with the code ?
I have different types of files in the folder .jpg .txt .rtf I don't know if that is why it is not working.

```
@echo off
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    cd c:\users\paul\desktop\11\
    set n=0
    for %%f in (*.*) do (
       set /A n+=1
       set "file[!n!]=%%f"
    )
    set /A "rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1"
    copy "!file[%rand%]!" c:\users\paul\desktop\12
```

Comment: works perfectly well for me!

Comment: I have about 50 files in the folder it copies the same one every time! I don't understand why it works for you and not me?

Comment: Maybe a path issue; put _all_ paths in between `""`, and use `%%~ff` instead of `%%f` in the `set` line, so the `!file[]!` array contains full paths...

Comment: I have 5 folders I want to copy random files from when I run the batch file . so I have copied and pasted the code from my original question 5 times into the batch file with the different paths for the different folders . it s not random for the first folder in the batch file but it is random for the bottom four!

Comment: Without any indication of the filenames involved, it's difficult to attempt to duplicate. Is there anything significant about the filename that is selected? Is it the first or the last or something like that? Try adding a line `echo %rand% %n%` just before the `copy` line. What figures are produced? Do they vary for the problem directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running this Batch file via a double-click from the explorer? When cmd.exe start execution it initialize the random seed with the current time, so if you execute the Batch file several times in a short lapse, and the number of different files to choose is small (like 50), the same file will be selected every time.

You may "randomize" the random number in several ways; this is one of the simplest methods:

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,%time:~-1%) do set "dummy=!random!"
```

Insert this line before the line that uses `%random%`.

Comment: I have always just put in a 1 second delay: `TIMEOUT /T 1 > nul`

Comment: no I'm not running the batch via double click from explorer . but I inserted your snippet of code and now its working ! thanks Aacini ! tx to everyone for their input!

Comment: @JasonFaulkner: I wrote a `test.bat` file with just `@TIMEOUT /T 1 > nul` and `@echo %time% = %random% >> random.txt` lines, and executed it _from a fresh cmd.exe session_ several times; the result shown that the random number varies in 100 units each 30 seconds aprox. (you may repeat this test and check my result). In this problem there are 50 files to choose so each one is selected by a range of 32768/50=655 random values, but the value of `%random%` just vary in 100 units each 30 seconds. In other words, your method select the same file during 655/100*30=196 seconds (more than 3 minutes).

Comment: @paul: If this answer solved your problem, you should select its green check mark; this informs other people that this question was solved. You may also upvote it if you think this answer is useful.